# ruby regexp Skipping Zero Length Matches and nil matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I have ruby app that uses first matched string by regex. `my_url.match(/my_regex/).first`
As a strings I have a list of urls that contain adress or postcode and from each of them I need to extract postocode or adreess by using regex 
Samples of urls:

```
http://www.adresses.co.uk/avon/bath-city
http://www.adresses.co.uk/postcode/rm107jj
```

My regex:

```
\.co\.uk\/postcode\/([^\/]*)|\.co\.uk\/(?!postcode)([^\/]*\/[^\/]*)
```

My problem is that for non postcode urls a first matched data by this regex is `nil` [see_on_rubular](http://rubular.com/r/SIpeFYMplA)
How to rewrite or change this reflex so it will skip nil matches or to make first matches non nils. I need to solve it with regex not in ruby coding please.

Comment: Ruby Oniguruma regex syntax does not support branch reset (as in PCRE) or same named captures rewriting (as .NET and PCRE). You can try `\.co\.uk\/([^\/\n]*\/[^\/\n]*)` and then check if the capture starts with `postcode/` (or you can get a match with `\.co\.uk\/\K[^\/\n]*\/[^\/\n]*`). If yes, it is a postcode, remove this prefix. There will be no pure regex solution I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex that captures in group #1 everything after `postcode/` if it's present, or else everything after `.co.uk/`:

```
\.co\.uk\/(?:postcode\/)?([^\/\n]+(?:\/[^\/\n]+)?)
```

([DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/SIpeFYMplA))

Note that this will give unexpected results if there are unwanted path elements at the end of a postcode link, such as:

```
http://www.adresses.co.uk/postcode/rm107jj/oops
```

**UPDATE:** Based on the comments, it looks like you want to match just the *last* path element.  But we can't simply capture the second element, because there might be only one:

```
http://www.adresses.co.uk/west-midlands
```

We can, however, make the first element optional:

```
\.co\.uk\­/(?:[^\/\n]+\­/)?([^\/\n]+­)
```

Notice how I used a non-capturing group for the optional portion, so the part you want is still captured in group #1.

...

Comment: But it does not solve a problem, there is still nil (empty match) as the first match on the non postcode url and only second match has value.

Comment: I don't understand.  When I do `my_url.match(/\.co\.uk\/(?:postcode\/)?([^\/\n]+(?:\/[^\/\n]+)?)/)[1]` in `irb` I get `avon/bath-city` for the first URL and `rm107jj` for the second.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: No, I need `bath-city` or `rm107jj`

Comment: So you want to capture only the second path element? `/\.co\.uk\­/[^\/\n]+\­/([^\/\n]+­)/` does that.

Comment: I just tried your last solution but could not make it work, it gives this error on rubular `Forward slashes must be escaped.` but they all are escaped

Comment: Sorry, I copied it with the delimiting slashes from `irb`.  This is what you need to paste into Rubular: `\.co\.uk\­/[^\/\n]+\­/([^\/\n]+­)`

Comment: Ah, no, it does not work for urls like this `http://www.adresses.co.uk/west-midlands` it should match 'west-midlands' in this case, but it does't